# RegEX - Match capital letters only, until first symbol occurrence

Tags: regex

I'd like to match:

```
LOVE-doesn'tMatterWhatComesAfterAnyways
```

Only allow capital letters before dash occurrence, and it doesn't matter what comes after it.

I came up with:

```
[A-Z]+?(?=-)
```

It does half of the job.

It does not allow: `love-doesn'tMatterWhatComesAfterAnyways`

But it does allow `lovE-doesn'tMatterWhatComesAfterAnyways`

Comment: Try using an anchor `^[A-Z]+(?=-)`

Comment: ...and see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jSyV15/1)

Comment: Thank you guys. Solved.